# How to create new table using date_part from the date table in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, datediff, date-difference

Hi I would like to know how I can create a new data set B from the given data set A using date_part function. I need to get all adjacent intervals but not all the intervals for each organization. (e.g. I do not need to get '2008-01-01 - 2005-02-22' for org 123). Could you share any idea to implement this?

Data set (A): table_a 
org_id date
123 2005-02-22 
 
123 2006-10-30 
123 2008-01-01 
234 2003-01-01 
234 2005-04-04

Data set (B): table_b 
org_id date_dif 
123 `DATE_PART('day', '2006-10-30' -  '2005-02-22')`  
123 `DATE_PART('day', '2008-01-01' -  '2006-10-30')`  
234 `DATE_PART('day', '2005-04-04' -  '2003-01-01')`

Comment: Hint: `select org_id, date, lead(date) over(partition by org_id order by date) as next_date from table_a;`

Comment: And you don't need `DATE_PART`; [date - date] gives you integer: days.

Comment: @Abelisto Thank you. It worked great. I did not know about window function.

Comment: Thank you @Adam.
I removed date_part and it works well.   
select org_id, date, next_date, (next_date - date) as date_diff
from (select org_id, date, lead(date) over(partition by org_id order by date) as next_date from test) as sub
where next_date IS NOT NULL